# if a StreamWriter variable is initialized inside an if statement and passed as an argument to Console.SetOut(), can it get GC'ed too soon?

Tags: c#, .net, console, streamwriter

I'm trying to decide if this StreamWriter variable should be declared as a field, a local, or as a local inside the if statement. My worry is that after I pass it to Console.SetOut() and execution continue past the if statement there will be no more references left to this object and it will get Garbage Collected.

Am I overthinking this or is it safe to assume that the Console class will reference it throughout the execution of my application?

Comment: If the question is "Am I overthinking it?", the answer is nearly always "Yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC <strike>counts</strike> will track references even if they've been passed around the application.  The GC should only collect objects if you have no way to access them any more.

Specifically, `Console.SetOut` keeps an internal reference to the `TextWriter` passed to it.

Comment: Be careful when you say "The GC counts references".  It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Sorry, it was poorly worded.  I meant counts as in matters, not as in is numerically counted.

Answer (score 4):

> after I pass it to Console.SetOut() and execution continue past the if statement there will be no more references left to this object

That assumption is incorrect: There will be a reference left to the object, namely a private field within `Console`. So, no worries about your stream writer getting GC'ed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are overthinking it... The GC will never collect anything that you may use. Just forget about it... You (should) have more important things to worry about...

The only rule regarding the GC I recommend you follow is that if a class implements IDisposable you must call .Dispose() or wrap it in a "using". Thant's it.